# how to use to_sentence for links?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

some thing like this:

John send a message to user1, user2, user3 and user4

this does not work

```
@users.collect{ |u| link_to(u.name, user_path(u)) }.to_sentence
```

Comment: Your example above works for me. What kind of output are you getting?

Comment: Thanks for alll the answers. I am using erector and that is probably why it does not work. It gives me link1 link2 link3 without comma and 'and'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ez,

`link_to` in Erector goes right to the output stream. You either need to replace `to_sentence`, patch into link_to's behavior, or replace link_to. As link_to in this context is simple, I'd recommend that:

```
  rawtext users.map { |u|
      "<a href='#{user_path(u)}'>#{u.name}</a>"
  }.to_sentence
```

Answer (score 4):

Odd...

```
@users.collect{ |u| link_to(u.name, user_path(u)) }.to_sentence
```

and

```
@users.map{ |u| link_to(u.name, user_path(u)) }.to_sentence
```

Should work.  What error are you getting?

Comment: this is awesome.  is there anyway to serve the link to if the url field is there and if not serve just the name?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are actually printing out the results with `<%= ... %>`, I know I sometimes forget the equal sign and spend a lot of time trying to figure things out.