# How do I generate a link within a .map block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a call like this:

```
<%= product.categories.map{|cat| cat.name}.join(', ').to_s + "." %>
```

What I would like to do, is something like this:

```
<%= product.categories.map{|cat| link_to cat.name, category_path(cat)}.join(', ').to_s + "." %>
```

When I do that, it actually spits out the path `/categories/1` as text and doesn't actually make it a link.

How do I generate the actual link within this block?

Thanks.

Edit: Anyone have any ideas about how to do this?

Comment: I think you want to map and then use to_sentence like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441328/how-to-use-to-sentence-for-links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to wrap the entire `map` result in `raw` like this:

```
<%= raw(@product.categories.map{ |cat| raw(link_to(cat.name, category_path(cat))) }.join(', ') + ".") %>
```

For a more full answer, [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096484/how-do-i-use-a-rails-link-to-helper-within-a-map-block-such-that-the-output-is).

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this

```
<% product.categories.each do |p| %>
 <%= link_to p.name, category_path p %>
<% end %>
```

**UPDATE**

Maybe try it like this

```
<% array =  product.categories.collect { |p| raw link_to p.name, category_path p } %>
```

This should save all your links in the array for further use. Now you can try

```
<%= array.join('., ') %>
```

Untested code. Note sure if this will work.

Comment: I know, but that wouldn't help me with the formatting - which is why I did it like this.

Comment: i.e. which is why I used the `.map` and the `join` - so I can format the output in the way I want. All I want to do is to add a link to that format.

Comment: Could you please paste your desired output?

Comment: Desired Output: `<a href="/categories/1">Men</a>, <a href="/categories/2">Women</a>.` where `Men` & `Women` are identified as `cat.name`. Note that there is a `,` and `.` included as part of the format - which is determined whenever `product.categories` is more than 1 object. If I have to use a bunch of `if` statements to get the formatting I want, it will be too verbose and look weird.

Comment: This definitely looks like it SHOULD work. It feels a bit inelegant though. If I don't get any other suggestions, then I will run with this. Just want something a bit more refined.

Comment: This doesn't work. It gives me a syntax error...unfortunately. :(