# How do I use a rails link_to helper within a .map block such that the output is an actual link, and not the text representation of the HTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this:

```
listed in <%= @product.categories.map{ |cat| raw(link_to(cat.name, category_path(cat))) }.join(', ') + "." %>
```

This is the output:

```
listed in <a href="/categories/1">Men</a>, <a href="/categories/2">Women</a>.
```

It doesn't actually convert that to an actual link. It spits it out as text on the webpage.

How do I get that `link_to` helper to be displayed as a link, and not HTML, from within that block?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you need to wrap the result of your `map` call with `raw`. This way you can tell rails that the string should be outputted directly into the template.

```
listed in <%= raw(@product.categories.map{ |cat| raw(link_to(cat.name, category_path(cat))) }.join(', ') + ".") %>
```

Comment: this just output the same html, not a clickable links.

The below will work Thanks to [This SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32774322/274087)

`<%= safe_join(links.map { |l| link_to(l.title, l.url) }, ", ".html_safe) %>`