# Can I make an array of links using link_to in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, join, link-to

I have a list of values in url/title pairs that I'd like to display.  (More specifically, each object has its own list of links, some with 0, some with 1, some with more.)  I would like them to appear in a list that is comma-separated.  So I wrote this in my .erb file:

```
<%= links.map{|wl| link_to wl.title, wl.url}.join(', ') %>
```

Somewhat to my surprise, this displayed a comma-separated list of *the HTML code for* the links I wanted to create; that is, it was taking all the angle brackets and ampersand-encoding them.  Just to make sure there wasn't anything funny in the higher-order functions, I tried a more imperative version:

```
<% a = [] %>
<% links.each do |wl| %>
  <% a << link_to(wl.title, wl.url) %>
<% end %>
<%= a.join(', ') %>
```

with, of course, the same result.  But I don't think I'm misusing `link_to`, because if I modify that to

```
<% links.each do |wl| %>
  <%= link_to(wl.title, wl.url) %>,
<% end %>
```

then it actually creates links.  It's *almost* exactly what I want, except that there's an extra comma after the last one.  Is there some magic going on under the hood with `link_to` that makes it act differently depending on where its output is heading?  Is there any way to bypass that magic?  The `join` semantics would be exactly what I want here, and I can obviously figure out how to roll my own (using each_index, I guess) but it seems like an awfully heavy and un-Ruby solution to what must be a common problem.

Comment: <%= links.map{|wl| link_to wl.title, wl.url}.join(', ').html_safe %> ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While the suggestions to use `html_safe` will get the result you are going for, I would suggest you not stick loops like that in your view. There is a perfectly good way in rails to do what you are looking for:

In your main view file where you currently have your loop change it to this:

```
<%= render partial: 'links/link', collection: links, spacer_template: 'shared/comma' %>
```

Then create a partial `links/_link.html.erb`

```
<%= link_to link.title, link.url %>
```

Then create a partial `shared/_comma.html.erb`

```
,
```

The nice thing about this approach is you don't have to worry if your link content is actually safe and if you choose to list or style it another way it's as simple as changing one or both of the templates. For example if instead of commas you decide you want it vertical and use `<br>` instead of `,` in your spacer template.

Comment: Aha thanks!  I had an inkling that there would be something like `html_safe`, but *this* is what I was really looking for---I knew there had to be an idiom for this.  Note for future readers of this question: I did have to force no-EOL-at-EOF for the file containing the link partial in order to prevent whitespace between the link and the comma, but once I did that it worked perfectly.

Comment: This has a lot of indirection.  Does not seem like the best design.

Comment: Indirection is generally bad for readability and maintainability.  Perhaps, if you explain why sticking loops in the view is bad, I would understand your reasoning more.

Comment: Martin, loops are bad in views because code is bad in views. It is not where it belongs. I wanted to stick to answering the original question, but to take it a step further I wouldn't even do what I proposed above. I would actually have a decorator/presenter backing this view with a method called `links` on it. That method would actually do basically what I have above so you would still have the partials but then your top level view can have something as simple as `<%= @my_presenter.links %>` which is infinitely more readable and understandable than a loop or  a chunk of array manipulation.

Comment: @AlexPeachey While I generally agree with the spirit of not having much code in a view, I think the ideal is not necessarily "no code" but rather "no logic". Iteration isn't logic and it's perfectly readable. Would you really have a partial whose contents is a single comma? That's not adding a lot of value; all you are doing is making the developers juggle more files in the name of making a simple list of stuff.

Comment: I would not personally have a partial that is a single comma, I was merely pointing out how one would do it. As I said in the previous comment above yours I would not even do what he is doing and would have something backing the view that knew how to make the comma-separated list of links (which may and likely would use some partials). For this answer I stayed with showing what Rails gives you in the framework. The proper way to render a collection of things is to use `render` with a collection and Rails even gives you a perfectly valid way of providing a separator.

Comment: To be clear, what @blahedo means by forcing no-EOL-at-EOF is that the link in `links/_link.html.erb` should be like this: `<%= link_to link.title, link.url -%>`. That is, the closing `%>` should instead have a dash, like this: `-%>`.

Answer (score 19):

Use `safe_join` combined with `html_safe` on the separator string.

Example:

```
<%= safe_join(links.map { |l| link_to(l.title, l.url) }, ", ".html_safe) %>
```

Comment: You're the king!

Comment: Is html_safe on comma needed? There is no html safe item for comma, right?

Comment: If you mix an not html safe string like `", "` with a safe html string the result is a not html safe string and will be escaped so you need to explicitly indicate that your constant string is html_safe.

Answer (score 12):

Try

```
<%= links.map{|wl| link_to wl.title, wl.url}.join(', ').html_safe %>
```

This instructs Rails to not escape the text.

Comment: I like this answer because it reduces indirection.  Indirection is generally bad for readability and maintainability.

Comment: be _very_ careful if you do this.  When wl.title comes from an external source this is an exploitable vulnerability. Use `h(wl.title)` or, better, use `safe_join`

Comment: @levinalex wouldn't `link_to` already returns a safe value? Can you give an example of exploit?

Answer (score 2):

Try putting this in your ApplicationHelper

```
  def sep(separator)
    ->(a, b){ a << separator.html_safe << b }
  end
```

Then do this in your template

```
links.map{|wl| link_to wl.title, wl.url}.reduce(&sep(", "))
```

You can use any separator you like this way. You also don't need to call `html_safe` on the whole thing either. Only the separator. So this method is more secure.

Answer (score 1):

Rails will convert strings to be html safe by default. Your join call turns the links output into a string, which is why the text is then being escaped. Try adding .html_safe after the join call, which will tell rails that the text you are providing is html safe and so does not need to be escaped. There's more on how this works at: http://yehudakatz.com/2010/02/01/safebuffers-and-rails-3-0/

Comment: This suffers from the same problem as Jim Lim's answer does an puts your code at risk to an easily exploited vulnerability.  Use `safe_join`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use RAW:

```
= raw inks.map{|wl| link_to wl.title, wl.url}.join(', ')
```

Or

```
= render partial: 'links/link', collection: links, spacer_template: 'shared/comma'
```

as suggested by Alex Peachey