# add links to comma separated list in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, link-to

I am transferring an unordered list with links to a comma separated list with links. I can make the comma separated list fine...but I can't figure out how to get the links into the comma separated list.

BEFORE

```
ul.list-unstyled
  - @cats.each do |c|
    = link_to animal_path(id: c.id)
      li
        =c.breed
```

AFTER

```
= @cats.each.map{ |c| c.breed }.join(",  ")
```

This is where I am lost.

Comment: Can you show a sample output about how it should look like ?

Comment: You need to wrap the result of your map call with raw. Check out [this.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14096519/3396429)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
@cats.map{ |c| link_to(c.breed,animal_path(c))}.join(", ").html_safe
```

Your current setup will display a list of cat breeds, but is not linking to anything, hence the use of the link_to call. This will return as escaped html unless otherwise specified, so you can make a call to html_safe to convert the resulting anchor tags to clickable links.